# How scroll to a specific point in scroll view using Java Script in IOS Automation

Tags: javascript, ios

How to scroll down or up to a point in a scroll view using Java Script in IOS Automation when the scroll is very big.

Comment: This is very vague — do you mean on a long web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using window.scrollBy(x,y) function